# wamp mysql on vista: unexplainable slow queries

Tags: mysql, windows-7, windows-vista, wamp

I am on vista, under WAMP, and the MySQL performance is disappointing me.

> C:\Users\dev>mysql -uroot
>   Welcome to the MySQL monitor. 
>   Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
>   connection id is 1 Server version:
>   5.1.41-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle
>   and/or its affiliates. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of
>   Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be
>   trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type
>   '\c' to clear the current input
>   statement.
>
> mysql> use crm Database changed
>
> mysql> select count(1) from participations;
>
> ```
> +----------+
> | count(1) |
> +----------+
> |   406015 |
> +----------+
> ```
>
> 1 row in set (2 min 33.11 sec)

I am sure the problem resides in vista and not wamp.
I read that some similar issues are dues to UAC activation, so we need to deactivate it.

I am on a laptop that I do not own, so I am looking for an alternative solution.

If you have one, please let us hear it.

Answer (score 2):

commenting the line in the drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
::1 localhost
```

improve very well the performance.

But the temporary table copy mechanism take time too.
I think, this is another problem

Comment: thanks for that hint... in my case connecting to 'localhost' took >1000ms vs. 6-9ms when connecting to 127.0.0.1 - looks like php tries to connect with mysql first to above IPv6 address, waits 1 second for response, and than connects to IPv4 127.0.0.1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Windows 8 Core I7 laptop.

When I changed the host from localhost to 127.0.0.1 things speeded up dramatically.